# Keeping selected dropdown value

Tags: php, html

I have this drop-down and user can select multiple options ,how can i keep selected value on form after submit button, if error comes on form

```
<select  onclick="document.getElementById('cand_qual4').style.display='none'; " name="oca[]" id="oca"  multiple="multiple">
<?php
      $odrop = array('B COM','M COM','BBA','MBA','LLB','LLM','CPA','CIMA','MS FINANCE','DISA','CISA','OTHER');

      foreach ($odrop as $odrop1)
      {
        echo '<option value="' . $odrop1 . '"' . (isset($_POST['oca']) && in_array($odrop1,$_POST['oca'])  ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $odrop1 . '</option>';
      } 
 ?>         
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: `echo '<option value="' . $odrop1 . '"' . (isset($_POST['oca']) && $_POST['oca'] == $odrop1 ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $odrop1 . '</option>';
` i have tried this but this not worked

Comment: Print post value of oca before foreach loop and check it's print correct value ? I have tried your code and its works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$_POST['oca'] == $odrop1
```

condition as `$_POST['oca']` would be an array, try

```
in_array($odrop1,$_POST['oca'])
```

Comment: update your code with that. did you get any error? turn error reporting on for E_ALL.

Comment: @raj : Please update your question with the code you mentioned.

Comment: @raj : take source and check if there is something getting printed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21743/discussion-between-mithunsatheesh-and-raj)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS-

```
echo '<option value="' . $odrop1 . '"' . (is_array($_POST['oca']) && in_array($odrop1,$_POST['oca'] ) ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $odrop1 . '</option>';
```

Comment: @raj What error you are getting, try to print_r($_POST['oca']) and see what its printing